# ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis [like.no.other]

Tags: sql, oracle

It is straightforward, but I can't understand it

```
select distinct PROJ_ID from APPS.BUS_PLAN_PROJ --> ok
(select distinct PROJ_ID from APPS.BUS_PLAN_PROJ) --> ok
select distinct PROJ_ID from APPS.BUS_PLAN_PROJ order by PROJ_ID DESC --> ok
```

but

```
(select distinct PROJ_ID from APPS.BUS_PLAN_PROJ
                                      order by PROJ_ID DESC) --> ORA-00907
```

It is just a small part of my real sql. Please help me

Note: I have googled but cannot get the answer

Comment: It will be hard to debug if we cannot see the full code.  Please edit your question and post your code.

Comment: The last statement is legal (although the brackets around it totally useless)

Comment: Yes, the last statement is a query , reused as subquery. I guess I can't do it that way. Sorry for asking silly question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume this is a subquery within a larger query since it's in brackets. `ORDER BY` is not valid subqueries, none that I can think of anyway. i suspect the order by is not needed or useful here. I suspect that oracle believes that the right parenthesis should be before the `ORDER BY` because the ordering should be applied on the outer query.

Comment: Yes, the last statement is a query , reused as subquery. I guess I can't do it that way. Thank you, accepted

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to use ORDER BY in subqueries connected by set operators.
[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd37a/57)